# Oracle Apex - ID column not incrementing based on the set sequence but rather to "t1000"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a sequence in oracle apex and linked the sequence to the row on the application end. However, on the master-detail form, it doesn't auto increment to the new Roster_ID when I try to add a new form record. What could be my mistake? Please help

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE ROSTER(
    Roster_ID NUMBER(5),
    Working_Hours NUMBER(2),
    Shift_Date DATE,
    Shift_End_Date DATE,
    Shift_ID NUMBER(5) REFERENCES Shift (Shift_ID),
    Ward_ID NUMBER(5) REFERENCES WARD (Ward_ID),
    Ward_Name VARCHAR2(25) REFERENCES WARD (Ward_Name),
    CONSTRAINT PK_ROSTER PRIMARY KEY (Roster_ID),
    CONSTRAINT CHECK_WORKING_HOURS CHECK (Working_Hours IN (6, 8, 12))
);
```

`CREATE SEQUENCE Roster_seq START WITH 5 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE NOCYCLE;`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Roster_T1
BEFORE
INSERT ON Roster
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.Roster_ID is NULL THEN 
    select Roster_seq.nextval into :NEW.Roster_ID from SYS.DUAL; 
  END IF; 
END;
/
COMMIT;
/
```

[image]

Comment: The txxx values is a "temporary key" in the client sode model as long as nothing is saved in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for a trigger; you could have set `roster_id`'s **default value** to sequence `roster_seq`.

Apart from that, set `roster_id` to be a

- hidden column (so that it is invisible)
- primary key
- value protected

If you then run a page and add a new row, Apex will let you enter all data you need, and save new row(s) along with the next sequence values in `roster_id` column.

---

If you want to see `roster_id`'s value, then create a new column, let's call it `roster_id_display` and set it to be

- display only
- its source is a database column named `ROSTER_ID` whose datatype is number
- set its query only property to yes

Now everything works: you can enter new rows and see IDs, but you can't (and shouldn't, anyway) change it via Interactive Grid.